# Sorting/Clustering similarity matrices

Tags: data-visualization, clustering, algorithms, covariance

I wonder, what are the available libraries in R or Python to do correlation matrix clustering (sometimes it is referred to clustering).

I also, wonder, after clustering/grouping each point. What is the most efficient and fast (not digging out pair of nodes again) way to rebuild and sort the matrix in a way that similar data are located together.

To explain this point more, for example there is a similarity matrix n*n and the clustering methods, has returned 1,2,3 as a label for each n label. Reordering this n*n matrix, in a way that all nodes with label 1 be together and same for 2,3 is challenging specially when the matrix is big.

Here is a nice example of the grouping process http://bost.ocks.org/mike/miserables/.

Comment: I tried, spectral analysis, but there is only one library in R for that which doesn't look promising. There are a couple of other clustering method, which usually spit out the label for each node; but they don't sort and re-order the matrix. It is also challenging after having labels, to reorder the similarity matrix.

Comment: It sounds a lot like a programming question, as the solution is conceptually very simple (sorting the rows and columns by their labels). The possible challenge rather lies in how to implement this solution with a programming language (R and Python are mentioned in the question, but the source code of the linked page shows how to do that with javascript). So I vote to close the question, as it's not really about data visualization, but about how to implement in R or Python this data visualization feature. The question is certainly a good fit for https://stackoverflow.com.